The effect of structure on the glass transition temperature of polymers in the case of cis and trans poly 1,4 butadiene
Why does poly trans 1,4 butadiene have a lower glass transition temperature than poly cis 1,4 butadiene?
My reading has led me to understand that a cis double bond lowers the energy barrier of rotation of an adjacent bond compared to a trans double bond, but I do not understand why this is the case.
